# List all tags associated from specific content type only?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm trying to make a view which is listing all taxonomy tags associated from nodes of a specific content type only.

How can I make this?

I can make a view which is listing all taxonomy tags, but I can't figure out how to filter it with a specific content type only.

Any ideas?

\Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Thomas - the answer is going to assume you are using Drupal 7, since you didn't specify.

Likely, the issue here is that you are using **Taxonomy terms** as the base of your view and therefore not able to select **Content: Type** as a filter.

To get that filter to show up, you need to add a **Relationship** (under the Advanced section of the view options) for **Taxonomy term: Content with term**.

After you do that, then **Content: Type** will show up in your filter list.